# Compressing multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list of numbers `mylist` and that I would like execute some code if all the elements of `mylist` are greater than 10. I might try

```
if mylist[0] > 10 and mylist[1] > 10 and ... :
    do something
```

but this is obviously very cumbersome. I was wondering if Python has a way of compressing multiple conditions in an if statement. I tried

```
if mylist[i] > 10 for i in range(len(mylist)):
    do something
```

but this returned an error.

I am using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt is pretty close. You just needed the `all` function to examine the results of the expression.

```
if all(mylist[i] > 10 for i in range(len(mylist))):
    do something
```

Incidentally, consider iterating over the items of the list directly, rather than its indices.

```
if all(item > 10 for item in mylist):
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
if all(x > 10 for x in myList):
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `all`:

```
if all(item > 10 for item in mylist):
   do something
```