# Python elegant way for many conditional statements in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a better more elegant / professional way to code the following

```
if A > 1 and B > 1 and C > 1 and A < 100 and B < 100 and C < 100:
    do something
```

?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370317/compressing-multiple-conditions-in-python)?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `all()` function, as well as chained comparisons

```
if all(1 < x < 100 for x in (A, B, C)):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `all()` rather than listing out each condition. This will make it easier to add new variables to check, if necessary:

```py
if all(1 < item < 100 for item in [A, B, C]):
    do something
```